# How to get AIC or BIC for glmmPQL (from nlme package)

Tags: r, nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am using `glmmPQL` (from nlme package) to run a multi-level glm with a dummy outcome. Unfortunately `glmmPQL` does not provide fit measures such as AIC, or BIC. I was wondering if there is a package that can calculate AIC, and BIC from`glmmPQL` results.

Comment: this may help answer the question: http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~mueller/SJS-02-117-Chiou.pdf

Comment: _"Since glmmPQL uses quasi-likelihood, technically there is no
log-likelihood (hence no AIC nor BIC, which are based on the
log-likelihood) for this model"_ (*@zhijie zhang* 2008, found here: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-December/181937.html)

Comment: Thank you, I also found this which talks about Quasi AIC-BIC: https://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/web/packages/bbmle/vignettes/quasi.pdf